# How make CRC-6 table

Tags: c, crc

Please let me know what's wrong with the code I made

```
void make_crc_table( void ) {       
    int i, j;       
    unsigned long poly, c;  

    poly = 0x03;    // X^6 + x + 1
        
    for ( i = 0; i < 256; i++ ) {       
        c = i >> 2;     
        for ( j = 0; j < 8; j++ ) {     
            c = ( c & 0x20 ) ? poly ^ ( c << 1 ) : ( c << 1 );      
        }       
        crctable[i] = (uint8_t) c;      
    }       
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Are you aware of [this fine document](https://archive.org/stream/PainlessCRC/crc_v3.txt)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to calculate starting at the high bit of the bytes. Get rid of the `>> 2` (that just results in doing the same calculation four times). Do this to calculate from the high bit:

```
c = c & 0x80 ? (c << 1) ^ (poly << 2) : c << 1;
```

Then when saving:

```
crctable[i] = (c >> 2) & 0x3f;
```

Not required, but there's no reason for the `unsigned long`, so just make that `unsigned`.

Comment: Thanks for your help.
I found the problem in my code and fixed it.